# Loading <div> with external content ONLY ater the web page is downloaded?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want one of the `<div>` placed in the web page to fill with contents, only after the main page is loaded. Now the issue is since the `<div>` content is of from an external url, the whole web page is causing to load slow as it is waiting for the `<div>` to finish loading external content. Some times external URL takes too much time, thus causing inconsistent performance for the running web page.

Which is the best way to accomplish this? via AJAX/ Jquery? If so how?

The `<div>` part is basically meant to display some kinds of Ads from an external url which return each ads as JSON objects...

Answer (score 2):

Very simple using jQuery. Load the page and then have a div as follows in the location you want the external content loaded to:

```
<div id="externalContainer">Loading data...</div>
```

By default this DIV contains the words "Loading Data...", and then when the page has loaded, you can make an AJAX request to load data from the external URL, and then present it in that DIV (overwriting the loading text).

Here is the jQuery code to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#externalContainer').html(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Failed to load external content');
        }
    });
});
```

This way, your page will be responsive to the user, and the external content will load the background.

Comment: I think you should replace ready with load .jQuery(window).load(function ()

Comment: For what reason @SajithaNilan?

Comment: How do you suggest to detect page loading finish?

Comment: @SajithaNilan why does it matter? With my suggestion, the AJAX call will begin as soon as the DOM is ready. Surely it's better to begin the AJAX request as soon as the DOM is ready, not when all of the page elements have loaded, otherwise you delay it's completion for no reason.

Comment: Yes,  i agree with Laurence as my purpose serves because i don't mind whether the window or DOM is ready first. In either way, it works to my requirements. Thanks Sajitha for your inputs

Comment: Laurance,  i see you have placed URL directly to external url inthe above script. In fact i have to extract JSON objects from external URL and display contents inside DIV  based upon few PHP conditions. In that case how it would be possible? Can we do PHP conditions in local file and set URL as the local file? Now i am using file_get_contents to extract JSON external file,  which seems to be very slow....

Comment: Can you re-write the above script to my requirement that i just commented?

Comment: Hi @JamesHayes, in my opinion it's best to do as little as possible client-side. Given your situation, it might be best to re-write it so that the URL points to a second PHP page of your own instead, and then use cURL to read the content from the remote page to your second PHP page. The second PHP page could then return HTML to the AJAX request. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok. Which is best CUrl or file_get_contents?

Comment: cURL will give you more control (e.g setting ports, SSL, GET or POST etc), but if you can get away with an easier route then go for it :) it might well be that the remote page will allow you to use file_get_contents just fine. cURL is a great fall-back though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AJAX** and jQuery's `$(window).load` event to accomplish this,

This is how you can do it,

```
$(window).load(function() {
     // Call AJAX function here.
});
```

In above code block within `.load()` function gets called only after the window is loaded completely. (e.g. Images,assets etc..)

Your AJAX function should load the content from external URL.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

After load the page do  yor ad loading part

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    alert('page is loaded');

   // Then send request to load Ads to <Div>

});
```